# Stripe API - Use different balances

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a stripe account which has two balances (JPY and USD). How to create a charge using specific balance? I'm creating a charge using USD currency, but it creates the charge for the JPY balance with following converting USD to JPY.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that USD is a valid settlement currency for your account's country to avoid the conversion. I recommend reading [this](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies/conversions#avoiding-currency-conversions) and [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payouts#supported-accounts-and-settlement-currencies).